# laravel backpack multiple file upload function error in edit item

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

now i use backpack laravel in my work and in add new item all thing is perfect,
but in edit the item i see this problem:

New Item : [Save New Item successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02IEK.png)

After Edit Item: [Edit Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gETJl.png)

Comment: Please avoid linking images and post code/text for the problematic parts (both the result as well as the code that generates the result).

Comment: Take another look at your mutator, I bet that's where the problem is. Must be something like setVendorPhotosAttribute on your model.